# Shear stress derivative in polar/cylindrical coordinates

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, stresses

I have an embarrassing question that I just can't seem to figure out. I have a fracture problem that is infinitely easier to solve in cylindrical coordinates. The boundary conditions, however, are expressed in cartesian coordinates Namely, at a particular surface:$$  \sigma_{xz}=0 $$

I just cannot figure out how to represent this in cylindrical coordinates. We were given a similar example in class notes where the boundary condition is: $$\sigma_{yz}=0$$and, we were just told that, in cylindrical coordinates, this is equivalent to $$\mu \frac{1}{r}  \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial \theta}|_{\theta = \pi}=0 $$ where $\mu$ is the shear modulus of the material.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to obtain a similar statement for $\sigma_{xz}$, or, similarly, show me how the statement for $\sigma_{yz}$ was obtained? I get that $$\sigma_{xz}=\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_3}$$. There's a step in the change of variables that I'm missing.